# If 2D array has already the element,I wanna put it into array which is already in there

Tags: python

If 2D array has already the element,I wanna put it into array which is already in there.
Now I have an array,

```
X = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 4, 5]]
```

I wanna replace this array into array Y.
In that time, if Y has already X's [1:3] element, I wanna put the X's element into Y's array. So, my ideal array Y is

```
Y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Now my code is

```
X = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [0, 4, 5], [1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
for i in range(7):
 if X[i][0] == 0:
    temp = [ set( X[0][1:3] ) ]
    print(temp)
    for x in X[i][1:3]:
      print(X[i][1:3])
      xSet = X[i][1:3]
      for y in temp:
        if not y.isdisjoint(xSet):
            y |= xSet
            break
        else:
          temp.append( xSet )
Y = [ list(x) for x in temp ]
print(Y)
```

But it errors,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/XXX", line 39, in <module>
    y |= xSet
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'set' and 'list'
```

I cannot understand why this error happen.
How can I fix this?How can I write this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Small note, these are *lists*, but more importantly, I do not understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain some more?

Comment: because you  are trying to perform set operation on the list!..
temp=[ set( X[0][1:3] ) ].. change that to temp=set( X[0][1:3] ) ..

Comment: My ideal output is [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

Comment: I wanna print out  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] in print(Y) in terminal.